# Generic TypeScript type guards with only generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

I want to build a generic type guard in TypeScript with the following signature:

```js
declare function typeGuard<T>(obj: any): o is T;
```

I found some articles (e.g. [this](https://dev.to/krumpet/generic-type-guard-in-typescript-258l)) and these solved it with a signature like this:

```js
declare function typeGuard<T>(obj: any, clazz: T): o is T;
```

But this requires one to carry around the type information through the code, so the first signature would be preferred.

The solution in the second case looks as follows:

```js
type typeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  boolean: boolean;
}

type PrimitiveOrConstructor =
  | string
  | { new (...args: any[]): any }
  | keyof typeMap;

type GuardedType<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor> = T extends { new(...args: any[]): infer U; } ? U : T extends keyof typeMap ? typeMap[T] : never;

function typeGuard<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor>(o: any, className: T): o is GuardedType<T> {
  const localPrimitiveOrConstructor: PrimitiveOrConstructor = className;
  if (typeof localPrimitiveOrConstructor === 'string') {
    return typeof o === localPrimitiveOrConstructor;
  }
  return o == localPrimitiveOrConstructor || (typeof localPrimitiveOrConstructor === 'object' && o instanceof localPrimitiveOrConstructor);
}
```

Which results in:

```js
typeGuard(2, 'number'); // true
typeGuard('foobar', 'string'); // true
typeGuard(new Foobar(), Foobar); // true
```

But what if I'm in a generic type context e.g. a function like this:

```js
declare function <T>func(arg: T);
```

In this case, it is not possible to do:

```js
function <T>func(arg: any) {
    if (typeGuard(arg, T)) { ... } // throws error: T is used as a value
```

So in this case I would prefer something like this:

```js
function <T>func(arg: any) {
    if (typeGuard<T>(arg)) { ... }
```

I recently have read [this](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab) article and tried to come up with something like this (which is of course not working):

```js
type Check<X, Y> = X extends Y ? true : false;
declare function check<C, T>(o: T): Check<T, C>;
```

and then use it like this:

```js
function <T>func(arg: any) {
    if (check<T>(arg)) { ... }
```

PS: just to be sure, I do not want to change the signature of the wrapping function to something like this `function <T>func(arg: any, clazz: T)` so that I can clazz in again.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you mean by `function typeGuard<T>(obj: any): o is T` because internally typeGuard has no way to know what `T` is. This is the reason why the the `clazz` example has a second parameter, to tell `typeGuard` at runtime what `T` is. It's also why it only supports primitives and class instances. So my question is: can you provide a sample implementation of `typeGuard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a fully generic type guard in typescript, because there's no type information at runtime. At runtime your functions can't know anything about T. See how the code of your function would be transpiled in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAngBwKYHEQEMBOAJgDwAqAfABRwBGAVgFyK5goCUTtdiMAzoqUQBvAFCJxifBigh8SLjzC8oLCBjjABAbhEBfEUA).

Whenever T would reach JS, it means that you use T as a value, not a type, and you get that error you mentioned: `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`,

And the resulting JS code is not type safe.

---

Let's take a look at what happens with currying. We start from the two parameter function you provided, but I'll swap the parameters, to get to the type guard

```js
function typeGuard<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor>(className: T, o: any): o is GuardedType<T>
```

The curried version of this function is:

```js
function curriedTypeGuard<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor>(className: T): (o: any) => o is GuardedType<T>
```

This acts like a factory for more specialized single parameter type guards.

```js
const stringSpecializedTypeGuard = curriedTypeGuard("string") // (o: any) => o is string
const classSpecializedTypeGuard = curriedTypeGuard(Class); // (o: any) => o is Class
```

The types are restricted by specifying the first parameter. 
Link to playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBKkLIEMxQLxQN4CgpQM7ACcBLAOwHMAuPQ0sgbmyhIFcBbAIwgKpY64ZzsA9kIA2EBCSrCxEkgwC%20mTLGgAFYqyLAiANwgB5AgGEhJfAWYBjYEIKpGAH2rFyTjEwgB3KAAoAdIEIBGS4VJIgANoAugCU4SQgUEo4zgDWECBCAGYw4BCIYAwq%20VAA4szBACYQVQAq%20QA8dVAQAB7AECRVuFAaRFo6%20kam5oTWtgQAfKhQLe2d3b3onl4BQSFhUBEx8VCk2VxQAKp0yVAA-CdQVPMdXT1QGVm5qoWXefBIkXXRN576AjFbLMEg2IhmT4QCrVZqte5LPqabR6QwmMwWCZ2Ka%20KyiBC4XAAOQQrAgtwANFAhAkQHshPtejCCDV6k06jMsDgrBjgFBREIrAhRP1BqiRrzLDY7FRRSjhuixlLJrM8QTiaSIAJ9rlfKocvzBcK5UM0aNMdL7ChrVAAOQWWi22IYRg4AgQYDMAgkKEGhnWtACoUi5GmiVKrFAxgpKDuz3e6moQNGkMDeVmyWRqCOZx6-IGoPG0PixUWlUBu1CdgAKwgNltUAAZI3E6R8JIrBACymTSXzeNLbFFMoQWCdJCrF7iLUGpBmVU4QsHr1ewr%208rsbj8QAvbe3Pa%20GnbRLOlAzBlEJmVFkz9mcxhxr0%20w-0xnla%20s2cQZozM9Q%20dbggu5UkIQ6YEomBqoSUDGPi0ErAoxQ8mMLi0AAypAVhEMKRDbrec4fqqU5EPh0Ifr4ABEDrkBRzoAPR0X4R4RKe55vtRZCQbyUBQbgGF1thoi4aR85EQQ05sgR1S%20LB6pDlADFMbSrGtr0smEsoQA)

So even with currying you can't implement your `func`.

Comment: Ok that sounds plausible, but could you explain then why the currying is working in the article I referenced? It was solely implemented with types and function declarations or am I missing something?

Comment: You can indeed curry the function with two parameters, but currying produces functions with more restricted type. I'll update my answer, as the comment is a bit small to house an example

Comment: Sorry for my English, but my question was not if I could implement my idea with currying but why the currying in the example works and my idea does not. I understand now that it does not, but why does the currying still works? In the article only types and function declarations are created, those are not transpiled, so the resulting JS should be erroneous, am I wrong?

Comment: The article shows only how to deal with currying from a typescript perspective. In order to use it at runtime, one needs to provide the implementation of the curry function as well (basically the javascript part). [Here](https://isurusiri.com/2017/10/07/rest-parameters-curry/) is one example of such implementation. It implements `CurryV5`. The last type definition (`Curry`) matches the implementation from the `Ramda` library, but the javascript for that is probably more complicated, just like `Curry` is more complicated then `CurryV5`

Comment: Ok thank you this confused me, I will mark your answer correct